# Why doesn't this await function run after res.end()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

[EDIT - SOLVED] An important piece of information not in the original question is that this function is running on Zeit Now serverless platform. Zeit functions stop processing after a `res.end` to keep uptime short. It was confusing because `console.log`s and other code was being run after the `res.end` but I assume because it wasn't taking any time to evaluate.

---

In this simple Node function, why isn't the `await` function running? I `res.end` early then want the rest of the function to run but it stops at the `await` function.

```
const fs = require("fs")
const bent = require("bent")
const buffer = bent("buffer")
const file_url = "http://klippr.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/mask.png"

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED")
  res.end("JOB ACCEPTED")

  console.log("STARTING JOB")
  console.log("BUT NOTHING AFTER THIS RUNS")

  fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/mask.png", await buffer(file_url))

  console.log("FILE DOWNLOADED")
  // do more stuff with the downloaded file..
}
```

When I call this function the file is never downloaded and the FILE DOWNLOADED log line doesn't run. Log:

```
REQUEST RECEIVED
STARTING JOB
BUT NOTHING AFTER THIS RUNS
```

If I change the `fs.writeFileSync` to a regular `fs.writeFile` and use a callback everything works as expected:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const bent = require("bent")
const buffer = bent("buffer")
const file_url = "http://klippr.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/mask.png"

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED")
  res.end("JOB ACCEPTED")

  console.log("STARTING JOB")
  console.log("BUT NOTHING AFTER THIS RUNS")

  // fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/mask.png", await buffer(file_url))
  fs.writeFile("/tmp/mask.png", buffer(file_url), () => {
    console.log("FILE DOWNLOADED")
  })

  console.log("FILE DOWNLOADED")
  // do more stuff with the downloaded file..
}
```

Now the file is downloaded and both FILE DOWNLOADED lines log to the console. But I like the sync method because it avoids callback soup.

So my question is why can't an await function run after res.end?

Comment: What exactly does `buffer(file_url)` return? Why do you think you need to `await` it?

Comment: @Bergi In reality I'm downloading several files and they all need to be complete before the rest of the function runs.

Comment: If the above is not your real code, we cannot really answer why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi the above is real functioning code. I simply changed the number of files downloading to avoid repetition. My issue is that the writeFile method doesn't run if it's an await call.

Comment: @Bergi added a comment to show that the function must continue after the last log but still, this is real functioning code.

Comment: All I can say is that changing from `writeFile` to `writeFileSync` won't make any difference for whether the file is written or not. But omitting the `await` keyword can make a large difference.

Comment: From looking at [the source](https://github.com/mikeal/bent/blob/master/src/nodejs.js), that `bent` library has some bugs where it doesn't properly report errors. Are you getting any unhandled rejections?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the tip. I'll add some more error handling and also try a different download library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do `fs.writeFileSync` without awaiting the buffer function like you do in `fs.writeFile`?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the function does run but when I check the file size after the `fs.writeFileSync` line it's not the complete file. It's only 16 bytes.